# "Cannot find -l<directory>" error - CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

My program includes a subdirectory, because a header and a source file are there which are needed. My project looks like this:

EDIT: Perhaps I didn't specify: my goal is to link frame_cap.cpp to the header grab_cut.h, as I require its functions.

```
[-] raspicam
 |  [-] main_folder
 |       frame_cap.cpp
 |       CMakeLists.txt
 |       [-] opencv-plus
 |            grab_cut.cpp
 |            grab_cut.h
 |            CMakeLists.txt
```

Now, I have already linked the two using the CMakeLists.txt in main_folder. It looks as follows:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(frame_cap)

SET(OpenCVPLUS_DIR "/home/pi/Desktop/raspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus")

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
SET(OpenCV_PACKAGE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE( frame_cap frame_cap.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( frame_cap ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})
```

As you can see, `OpenCVPLUS_DIR` is, well, the opencv-plus directory, where both the header and source file are located. The CMakeLists.txt file in the opencv-plus folder looks as follows:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(grab_cut)

SET(OpenCVPLUS_DIR "/home/pi/Desktop/raspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus")
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
SET(SOURCES grab_cut.cpp ${OpenCVPLUS_DIR}/grab_cut.h)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(grab_cut grab_cut.cpp ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(grab_cut ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Finally, this is the exact error I get:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable frame_cap
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lraspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus/
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/frame_cap.dir/build.make:102: frame_cap] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/frame_cap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I'd be happy to hear your suggestions as I'm a newbie at CMake and am not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is a lot of code that can be cleaned up here, but there's one question. Why are you trying to *link* one executable to another? Do you intend for `frame_cap` and `grab_cut` to *both* be executables? Or should one be built as a *library*, then **linked** to your executable?

Comment: Hey @squareskittles, I've tried to be as careful as possible with the code and because I'm not always sure what's correct, it looks pretty bad, I agree. About the executables: I thought that adding the grab_cut executable would be necessary for its CMakeLists.txt file to actually work.. What I actually intend to do is to link frame_cap.cpp to the header grab_cut.h. So I guess that would mean the grab_cut executable should be linked.

Comment: You can create both executables, and also use the `grab_cut` header as an include file in `frame_cap.cpp`. Is that what you intend? To be clear, header files aren't *linked*, per se. They are included in the compilation of libraries or executables.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lraspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus/
```

occurs because you try to *link* a directory to your `frame_cap` executable here:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( frame_cap ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})
```

This doesn't make sense; only **libraries** should be linked to your executable.

From your comments, it sounds like you want to build two executables, but use the `grab_cut` functions in both. This is certainly achievable with CMake. But you appear to have a design problem, because compiling the `grab_cut.cpp` file with the `frame_cap` executable will probably cause issues, assuming both files contain a `main` function. You'll need to **split** the `main` function into a separate file (say, `main.cpp`), then you can include `grab_cut.cpp` in the compilation of both executables.

BTW, you can use [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) to refer to the directory of the current CMakeLists.txt file, so there is no need to list out directories in your source-tree explicitly. Also, I pray you are using a newer CMake than version 2.8. Some of the steps in your CMake files seemed unnecessary, so here are the simplified files that might work for you.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(frame_cap)

# There is no need to spell out this directory since it exists 
# in the source-tree already.
SET(OpenCVPLUS_DIR "/home/pi/Desktop/raspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus")

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
# Seems unused, remove it.
SET(OpenCV_PACKAGE ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

# Include the OpenCV and opencv-plus headers in this executable.
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/opencv-plus)
# There is no library to link from this directory, so we don't need this call.
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(opencv-plus) 

# Add the grap_cut.cpp file to the frame_cap executable.
ADD_EXECUTABLE( frame_cap frame_cap.cpp opencv-plus/grab_cut.cpp)
# We don't link anything from opencv-plus, we compiling it directly.
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( frame_cap ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${OpenCVPLUS_DIR})
```

And your `opencv-plus/CMakeLists.txt` file can be simplified to something like this:

```
# If this CMake file is always called as part of the top-level CMake 
# file, don't need this.
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(grab_cut)
# Don't need this, as explained earlier.
SET(OpenCVPLUS_DIR "/home/pi/Desktop/raspicam/main_folder/opencv-plus")
# The top-level CMake file already found OpenCV, so the variables 
# we need are already defined.
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# The include directories get initialized from the parent CMake file, so no need 
# for this call if the include directories are the same for both executables.
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Separate 'main' function into separate file, and add it here.
SET(SOURCES grab_cut.cpp grab_cut.h main.cpp)

# Don't need to add 'grab_cut.cpp' to the executable twice! It was 
# already added using the 'SOURCES' variable.
ADD_EXECUTABLE(grab_cut grab_cut.cpp ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(grab_cut ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I implemented all you've told me, but now I seem to be getting "undefined reference errors" which are too long to post here. It seems like the grab_cut files still somehow don't get recognized?

Comment: @RaresTudor Ok, it sounds like you have a more fundamental design problem, which I initially did not understand from your post. It seems you’ll want to separate grab_cut into grab_cut.cpp and main.cpp. This way, the main function can be placed in main.cpp, and the grab_cut functions placed into grab_cut.cpp. Then, grab_cut.cpp should be listed in both calls to `add_executable`.

Comment: @RaresTudor I modified my response based on your feedback, and to clarify my earlier comment. Apologies for the misunderstanding earlier, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works now. @squareskittles